# How to mount swap?

Tags: swap

My RAM was 2gb.But i gave 8gb for swap region and accidentally it was unmounted.how to mount it.
    And sometimes my laptop was strucked and not operating again
    Does the swap region uses as ram ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Swap partition is never mounted.

Comment: You may be looking for `swapon`.

Comment: Thanks i checked it,swap was never mounted.but it was not activated.And it was inactive when i starts it.please help me to fix always active the swap.Does the swap area uses as ram

Answer (score 0):

Normally (IMHO), `swap` is set up in `/etc/fstab`, and activated by `sudo mount -a` or via `swapon`. The `/etc/fstab` `swap` entry on my Ubuntu 16.04.1 reflects my use of encrypted home directories (and therefore, encrypted swap), YMMV.

```
/etc/fstab:
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=339b7a56-3b67-47e8-87e1-f483296a39bd none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

I started with a simple `swap` line:

```
/dev/sda1  none swap  sw  0  0
```

Re-identified my swap partition by UUID:

```
UUID=339b7a56-3b67-47e8-87e1-f483296a39bd none            swap    sw              0       0
```

then ran:

```
sudo /usr/bin/ecryptfs-setup-swap
```

You should:

```
for m in fstab mount ecryptfs-setup-swap swaopn ; do
    man $m
done
```